# Adjusting whole site size which is fixed on px?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, zooming, pixel

I made a site in which is fully sized with pixels and not percent, just like in the code preview below.

However It turned out that on screens with a small resolution you cannot see the site porperly. And the user has to zoom out in the browser to see the site properly.

Is there any easy way to fix that issue? **such as a making a media query for browser zoom or something like that?**

```css
.fixed1, .fixed2, .fixed3{
  margin:0 auto;
}

.fixed1{
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:green;
}

.fixed2{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-color:red;
}

.fixed3{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed1">
  <div class="fixed2">
    <div class="fixed3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a **viewport meta tag** inside **head tag**

```
<head>
    <!--other tags...-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

I have tested it with mobile devices which have screen size smaller than 400.

Comment: but viewport is only for mobile devices, isn't it?

I would also need it for PC's with smaller resolutions.

Comment: It working every devices not just the mobile devices, pls try on real device to see the result

Comment: I tryed it but it didn't archive my goal.

The problem is that the height of the page should always be the same, so that no scroll bar appears.